# Passing 2/n-number of (multiple) parameters to 'int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway'

Tags: spring-integration

Hi guys i need help here :)

Previously when I tried to pass only one variable, it was working fine. Now as soon as I am trying to pass 2/n-number of parameters by using Spring Integration, getting following 'payload' exceptions, which I am not clear about.

Exception I am getting is as follows:

```
[2014-10-31 12:12:43,943][WARN ]GatewayProxyFactoryBean$MethodInvocationGateway.doSendAndReceive: failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to convert object to Message
    at org.springframework.integration.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter.toMessage(SimpleMessageConverter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:112)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:103)
...

Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: At most one parameter (or expression via method-level @Payload) may be mapped to the payload or Message. Found more than one on method [public abstract java.util.List com.dao.PersonalinfoDao.queryExecute(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.throwExceptionForMultipleMessageOrPayloadParameters(GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.java:235)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.access$400(GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper$DefaultMethodArgsMessageMapper.toMessage(GatewayMethodInboundMessageMapper.java:337)
...
```

Bellow showing what I am doing for passing 2 parameters:

In my `PersonalinfoDao.java` file I have this:

```
public interface PersonalinfoDao {
/** Method to call a SQL query using spring integration mechanism */    
public List<PersonalInfo> queryExecute(String firstname, String lastname);
```

}

In my `PersonalinfoService.java` file I have this:

```
public class PersonalinfoService {

@Autowired
private PersonalinfoDao personalinfoDao;

public List<PersonalInfo> dbConnect(String firstname, String lastname) {
    List<PersonalInfo> personalinfoList = personalinfoDao.queryExecute(firstname, lastname);        
    return personalinfoList;
}
```

}

In Gateway definition file I have the following:

```
<!-- Mapper Declarations -->    
<bean id="personalinfoMapper" class="com.support.PersonalinfoMapper"/> 

<!-- Service Inheritance -->
<bean id="personalinfoService" class="com.service.PersonalinfoService"/>

<!-- Channels = For calling DAO interface methods in Spring Integration Mechanism one has to create request & response channels --> 
<int:channel id="procedureRequestChannel"/>

<!-- Gateway = DAO Interface Method Mapped to Request & Response Channels -->   
<int:gateway id="gateway_personalinfo" default-request-timeout="5000"
             default-reply-timeout="5000"
             service-interface="com.dao.PersonalinfoDao">
    <int:method name="queryExecute" request-channel="procedureRequestChannel" />
</int:gateway>

<!-- Stored Procedure Outbound-Gateway = To call a database stored procedure -->        
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway  id="outbound-gateway-storedproc-personalinfo"
                                        request-channel="procedureRequestChannel"
                                        data-source="dataSource"
                                        stored-procedure-name="pkg_personalinfo_spring.proc_personalinfo_spring"
                                        expect-single-result="true"
                                        ignore-column-meta-data="true">
    <!-- Parameter Definitions -->                                      
    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition  name="firstname" direction="IN"/>
    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition  name="lastname" direction="IN"/>
    <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="get_ResultSet" type="#{T(oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes).CURSOR}" direction="OUT"/>

    <!-- Parameter Mappings Before Passing & Receiving -->                              
    <int-jdbc:parameter name="firstname" expression="payload"/>
    <int-jdbc:parameter name="lastname" expression="payload"/>
    <int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="get_ResultSet" row-mapper="com.support.PersonalinfoMapper"/>

</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

I know that i am doing something wrong in this above gateway definition specially when using `expression="payload"`...because for any given Getway i can use only one `payload`. But as I am not clear how to do that by using Map/Array/List, can any one plz help me to resolve this?

Thank u so much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to use a `@Payload` annotation:

```
public interface PersonalinfoDao {

    /** Method to call a SQL query using spring integration mechanism */    
    @Payload("#args")
    public List<PersonalInfo> queryExecute(String firstname, String lastname);    

}
```

Or use a `payload-expression="#args"` in the XML declaration of the `<gateway/>`'s method.

The framework will then make the payload an `Object[]` and you can use `payload[0]`, `payload[1]` etc in your expressions.

Comment: Thank u so much Gary. I actually used @Payload annotation in my interface class as u suggested and later in XML used payload[0], payload[1]...Now it is working perfectly fine :)