# Dealing with stored procedure return value and one/two cursors with n-number of returned columns by 'int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway'

Tags: spring-integration

So far I was able to pass n-number of parameters to stored procedure (Oracle) from front end and receive one cursor (with n-number of columns) from back end (Thanks to [Gary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240763/gary-russell) for his great suggestion [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26716061/passing-2-n-number-of-multiple-parameters-to-int-jdbcstored-proc-outbound-ga) ).

However, the following scenario still i couldn't resolve where I am trying to receive not only just one cursor (with n-number of columns) but a return value along with n-number of cursors (with n-number of columns) from back-end. I need help :)

So far what i have done is as follows:

In my `pkg_personalinfo_spring.proc_personalinfo_spring` having the following Spec:

```
procedure proc_personalinfo_spring(
        firstname       in  VARCHAR2,
        lastname        in  VARCHAR2,
        p_RetVal       out  VARCHAR2,           //Previously I was trying without such kind of p_RetVal 'out' variable and it was working. As soon as I added this 
                                                //started   getting exception 
        p_ResultSet    out  sys_refcursor);
```

In the body of my stored proc having this:

```
...
p_RetVal := '1';

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN p_RetVal := p_RetVal || 'proc_settlement_report: SQLCode: ' || SQLCODE || ' SQL Error Msg: ' || SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 1950); dbms_output.put_line('Error');

  RETURN;
...
```

Now to use `p_RetVal` (which is my return value) along with my one cursor so far, I did these are the changes:

a) In `PersonalinfoDao` I added new getter and setter for `p_RetVal`:

```
String p_RetVal;

public String getP_RetVal() {
    return p_RetVal;
}

public void setP_RetVal(String p_RetVal) {
    this.p_RetVal = p_RetVal;
}
```

b) And in `Mapper` class added the following line:

```
...
PersonalInfo personalInfo = new PersonalInfo();

        try{
            personalInfo.setP_RetVal(resultSet.getString(DBConstants.P_RETVAL));
            feedInfo.setFirstname(resultSet.getString(DBConstants.FIRSTNAME));
            feedInfo.setLastname(resultSet.getString(DBConstants.LASTNAME));
...
```

c) Finally in `Gateway` definition file I have the following changes:

```
<!-- Stored Procedure Outbound-Gateway = To call a database stored procedure -->        
    <int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway  id="outbound-gateway-storedproc-personalinfo"
                                            request-channel="procedureRequestChannel"
                                            data-source="dataSource"
                                            stored-procedure-name="pkg_personalinfo_spring.proc_personalinfo_spring"
                                            expect-single-result="true"
                                            ignore-column-meta-data="true"
                                            skip-undeclared-results="true">
        <!-- Parameter Definitions -->                                      
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition  name="firstname" direction="IN"/>
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition  name="lastname" direction="IN"/>
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="p_RetVal" type="VARCHAR" direction="OUT"/>
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="get_ResultSet" type="#{T(oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes).CURSOR}" direction="OUT"/>

        <!-- Parameter Mappings Before Passing & Receiving -->                              
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="firstname" expression="payload[0]"/>
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="lastname" expression="payload[1]"/>
        <int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="p_RetVal" row-mapper="com.ge.far.support.FeedinfoMapper"/>
        <int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="get_ResultSet" row-mapper="com.support.PersonalinfoMapper"/>

</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

Now, When I am running the app, getting following exceptions:

```
...
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call PKG_PERSONALINFO_SPRING.PROC_PERSONALINFO_SPRING(?, ?, ?)}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 3:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROC_PERSONALINFO_SPRING'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:231)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1135)
...
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:170)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 3:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROC_PERSONALINFO_SPRING'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
```

Plz help me to find out where I am doing mistake(s). I also need to deal with a situation where there will be one return variable (such like `p_RetVal`) as we as n-number of cursors (sys_refcursor) in my result set.

Thanks again everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `p_RetVal` is `VARCHAR` `OUT` param you can't use the `returning-resultset` for it.

Just remove the `<int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="p_RetVal">` definition and the result `payload` of the `<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>` will contains a `Map` with two keys: `p_RetVal` as `String` and `get_ResultSet` as `List<PersonalInfo>`.

Of course you should get rid of `DBConstants.P_RETVAL` in the `PersonalinfoMapper` and the `FeedinfoMapper` is redundant.

`<int-jdbc:returning-resultset>` is only for the `CURSOR` procedure `OUT` params.

Comment: Owau! What a Coincidence!!! I just did the same thing what u suggested Artem. See...i read ur mind ;) Thank u so much

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after little research i think got a little clue which can be a solution to the above scenario(s).

**First:** in my Gateway definition file i changed 'expect-single-result' attribute's value to 'false' in 'int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway' element. This is logically correct because my stored proc will be returning more than one result-set objects.

**Second:** I added the following line in my Gateway definition file:

```
<int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="p_RetVal" direction="OUT"/>
```

So currently it looks like as follows:

```
<!-- Stored Procedure Outbound-Gateway = To call a database stored procedure -->        
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway  id="outbound-gateway-storedproc-personalinfo"
                                            request-channel="procedureRequestChannel"
                                            data-source="dataSource"
                                            stored-procedure-name="pkg_personalinfo_spring.proc_personalinfo_spring"
                                            expect-single-result="false"
                                            ignore-column-meta-data="true">
        <!-- Parameter Definitions -->                                      
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition  name="firstname" direction="IN"/>
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition  name="lastname" direction="IN"/>
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="p_RetVal" direction="OUT"/>
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="get_ResultSet" type="#{T(oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes).CURSOR}" direction="OUT"/>

        <!-- Parameter Mappings Before Passing & Receiving -->                              
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="firstname" expression="payload[0]"/>
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="lastname" expression="payload[1]"/>
        <int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="get_ResultSet" row-mapper="com.support.PersonalinfoMapper"/>

</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

**Third:** as i am not defining 'p_RetVal' under 'Parameter Mappings Before Passing & Receiving' section that means i will not use 'p_RetVal' for mapping in my Java code. Therefore, i deleted 'String p_RetVal;' from 'PersonalinfoDao' and its getter and setter.

**Forth:** Due to third step, I also modified my Mapper class as follows:

```
...
PersonalInfo personalInfo = new PersonalInfo();

        try{
            feedInfo.setFirstname(resultSet.getString(DBConstants.FIRSTNAME));
            feedInfo.setLastname(resultSet.getString(DBConstants.LASTNAME));
...
```

That's all! really???

Yes!!!...but there is a catch...well, i was not sure till this far that my code will run without exceptions. But after running the App with all those little changes i saw no exceptions and so started little debugging what is going on through 'FIDDLER' (My best friend lah ;) ), where i saw the following JSON object return from back-end. Yahoooooooooo...means Spring Integration is on its action :)

```
JSON
  - {}
     -  p_ResultSet
     -   -{}
     -     -    firstname=Faisal
     -     -    lastname=Quazi
     -  p_RetVal=1
```

Now, the catch is as u already noticed that in  Gateway definition file I defined 'p_RetVal' under 'Parameter Definitions', I didn't define that under 'Parameter Mappings Before Passing & Receiving'. This part i am still not sure WHY or HOW it is working in background.

So at this very moment, u can consider this answer of mine not an ultimate solution but may accept it as by-passing the deadlock situation. Spring Integration Experts might have some good say on this :)